# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python, json, image, attributeerror, urlrequest

I am connecting to the API that returns a JSON object with several pieces of data and use that data to build an html page. I am having trouble with downloading a local copy of the image using python and including the image tag linking to the image. When I run the code, I receive the error stating `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has not attribute 'content'`. I have the following code:

```
    import urllib.request
    import json
    out = open('outfile.txt','w')
    link = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key="
    print(link)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = resp.read()
    print(str(data, 'utf-8'))
    returnJson = json.loads(data)
    img_url = returnJson['url']
    title = returnJson['title']
    current_date = returnJson['date']
    print(img_url)
    print(title)
    print(current_date)
    resp = urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url)
    img_file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(img_file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: Could you add the full error output? In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Why use [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) if you're going to write to the file yourself?

Comment: Here's the full error output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: It occurs at the last line of the code. 'f.write(resp.content)

Comment: Honestly, I have been playing around with the code for a minute trying to figure out what exactly to do with the image and how to pull the json and then use the image URL to pull the image into .jpg file.

Comment: I have never dealt with the images in python, and am learning.

Answer (score 0):

urllib.request.urlretrieve returns a tuple, which doesn't have a content attribute. Instead, it copies the content to a local file. Moreover, this function is legacy and may be deprecated in the future, according to the docs. I would recommend following the advice in the [urllib.request docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), which is:

> The [Requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your API key is in your question - you might want to edit that out so no one else uses it!

The error is in the last line of the sample you've given us

```
f.write(resp.content)
```

At this point, `resp` is set to the response of `urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url)`. However, `urllib.request.urlretrieve` actually returns a **tuple** - `(filename, headers)`. The `filename` is where the downloaded resource is stored on the system, and `headers` is the response headers for the request.

Modifying your code, I believe this might be more what you want?

```
    import os
    
    #rest of your code here
    
    (filename, headers) = urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url)
    img_file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
    os.replace(filename, img_file_name)
```

EDIT: `os.rename` doesn't seem to like existing files, however [os.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) does!

Comment: It's not enough to edit out the API key. It will still be in the edit history, and a bad actor may have already grabbed it anyway. Change the API key instead.

Comment: I generated another API, thanks for that. It is now generating an error that the file already exists? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @krappold it is worth checking that img_file_name is what you're expecting (e.g. `print(img_file_name)`. Also, `os.rename` doesn't seem to like existing files, but `os.replace` should do!